# Unable to access jarfile - PowerShell vs PowerShell Core

Tags: java, powershell, jar, powershell-core

I am using PowerShell script to start a Java application.

```
$app = Start-Process -FilePath java -ArgumentList "-jar $path_to_jar" -PassThru
```

OR

```
java -jar $path_to_jar
```

When I am running this script, in **PowerShell Core** it's executing properly , but if I run the same script in normal **PowerShell** (Windows PowerShell) - it's giving error "**Unable to access jarfile**"

Even if I run PowerShell (Windows PowerShell) with Admin privilege getting same result, whereas PowerShell Core working without Admin Privileges

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does `$path_to_jar` contain a relative or absolute path? Windows PowerShell does not update the process working directory when you change location with `cd`/`{Set,Push,Pop}-Location`, so relative paths passed to executables (like `java.exe`) might resolve differently

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - seems like this is the issue - JAR path causing this issue

Comment: Try calling `[environment]::CurrentDirectory = $PWD` right before invoking java in Windows PowerShell

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen - it solved my issue.